# BinarySearch in two dimensional list

Tags: c#

I have dimensional list:

```
List<List<string>> index_en_bg = new List<List<string>>();

   index_en_bg.Add(new List<string>() { word1, translation1 }); 
   index_en_bg.Add(new List<string>() { word2, translation2 }); 
   index_en_bg.Add(new List<string>() { word3, translation3 });
```

I would do binary search by the first column (words), something like this:

```
int row = index_en_bg.BinarySearch(searchingstr);
```

but it works only for a one-dimensional list. How would I extend it to work for two-dimensional lists in my case? I don't want to use `Dictionary` class.

Comment: Up vote for first question! Welcome :)

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you don't want to use a dictionary?

Comment: @Patrick My English is not so good, it's hard to explane for me, sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case you need to provide your own customer IComparer-implementing comparator

```
public class Comparer: IComparer<IList<string>>
{
    public int Compare(IList<string> x, IList<string> y)
    {
        // base the comparison result on the first element in the respective lists
        // eg basically
        return x[0].CompareTo(y[0]);
    }
```

And you'll call it like this, offering a List where only the field you're searching is filled in.

```
int row = index_en_bg.BinarySearch(new List<string>() {searchingstr},new Comparer());
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `IComparer<IList<string>>`?

Comment: I did it this way:

        `public class MyBinComparer : IComparer<List<string>>>
        {
            public int Compare(List<string> x, List<string> y)
            {
               StringComparer comparer1 = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
                return comparer1.Compare(x[0], y[0]);
            }
        }`

`int row = index_en_bg.BinarySearch(new List<string>() {searchingstr}, new MyBinComparer());`

but it doesn't work correctly, BinarySearch returns me always integer bigger than the last item in index_en_bg

Comment: @vinsa are you sure the items in index_en_bg are well sorted?  Ie, alphabetically by the first element of each contained list? Bbecause if they aren't you can't perform a binary search.

Comment: @vinsa and it should be quite clear by now that not using a Dictionary is making you jump through all kinds of hoops - maybe you should explain why Dictionary isn't an option for you, as it's the natural fit for your problem.

Comment: @fvu because I have to use BinSearch, it finds translation even you write part of a word, Dictioanry[key] will return null if you write only part of a word. If you write **ca** or **cats**, BinSearch will reaturn **cat**, but Dictioanry['ca'] will return null.
And yes, the list is sorted.

Comment: @vinsa that depends on your comparer, as long as your comparer doesn't handle partial matches correctly it won't.  And honestly what you're trying to do here sounds extremely tricky: how to handle a case where `ca` `cat` and `cats`  all exist?  You cannot be sure it will find the best match using crude binary search.

Comment: @fvu I can't explane but disctionary is not for me (my English is not so good), tell me if you know why my example return always bigger integer than last item in the list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30756/discussion-between-fvu-and-vinsa)

Comment: I did some tests, your code is working, but I'm wrong somewhere, I will try to find where, tank you, this questions is resolved.

Comment: Great.  Don't hesitate to create a new question should you run into further problems - that's more productive than adding problems to existing question (a new question will be seen by more people than an already hours-old one).

Answer (score 2):

Well as far as I understand you should use `Dictionary<K,V>` instead, this way:

```
// 1 creating the dictionary
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic["word1"] = "translation1";
dic["word2"] = "translation2";
dic["word3"] = "translation3";

// 2 finding a translation
var trans = dic["word1"];
```

And `Dictionary<K,V>` is really performant.

But if you insist on using `BinarySearch` you can implement `IComparer<List<string>>` and pass it to the function.

Comment: But then OP said he didn't want to use Dictionary...  Which is puzzling, but part of his requirements.

Comment: Yes; it was puzzling for me too; so I added the IComparer<List<string>> option.

Answer (score -1):

As you always search using the first item of the list you could use dictionary too.

```
    var d = Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

as answered previously it's preforms much better than List.

Comment: On stackoverflow you normally leave a comment or upvote instead of writing a new answer if you agree. Since you only have 1 rep point you can't leave comments yet but you can upvote the answers you like.